# How to display chat users list in the chronological order using firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a requirement of arranging chat users based on their most recent messages which they have sent to the user using firebase chat. I have tried using order by the query based on timestamp, but it's not working for me. Please find my code below and database structure here

[image]

```
   mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                final Query databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseConstants.USERS).child(mFirebaseUser).child(FirebaseConstants.COLLEGEMATES).orderByChild("timestamp");
                final DatabaseReference databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseConstants.USERS);
                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Student> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Student>().setQuery(databaseReference, Student.class).setLifecycleOwner(getActivity()).build();
                firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Student, FirebaseListViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FirebaseListViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Student model) {
                        try {
                            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
}
```

Comment: You should have a `timestamp` field in your `collegemates` nodes.

Comment: Where in your code are you using a query based on timestamp? I also cannot see a property of type timestamp in your database. Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: sorry guys i posted a wrong image but i am timestamp node in my child @AlexMamo

Comment: You should do what @RenaudTarnec mentioned in his comment.

Comment: @AlexMamo please check my structure i have edited my question

Comment: Please show us what are the values for all of those constants in your reference.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the child at every message named "createdAt" added with this snippet:

```
            String patternForDateExtended = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
            DateFormat dff = new SimpleDateFormat(patternForDateExtended);
            Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            String timeString = df.format(today);
            String rightNowEverything = dff.format(today)+rightNow.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

**for example the output will be a crescent number like 20190404132156825**

and then ordering the messages with this:

```
     myRef.orderByChild("createdAt").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

// adding to the recycleview everything.


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Hope that will help you, keep coding :)